# Problems booting, any way to log this to a file?

Tags: boot, logfiles

Is there any way to capture the log of the boot process you see on screen to a file on the FAT partition when it's not getting to the point of booting from the root fs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you have to derive a serial console out of the GPIO of the Raspberry Pi and then connect it to your development PC. [This post](https://blogs.oracle.com/speakjava/entry/serial_communications_with_a_raspberry) and [this page](http://www.element14.com/community/groups/raspberry-pi/blog/2012/07/18/look-ma-no-display-using-the-raspberry-pi-serial-console) show how to do it. However you'll need some basic knowledge in electronics to have it work properly.

Comment: Thanks, I guess until I get this, I will just have to transcribe error messages from the screen.

Answer (score 3):

You may not be able to create a file, but you can go low tech and hookup a VCR or use a camcorder to capture the text as it scrolls across the screen.